# How can I get the detail usage of physical memory in linux?

Tags: linux, memory

I have a Dell R740 server with 16G*12 memory installed. In theory I can see total 192G memory in linux, but in fact the kernel only report 187G total memory. How can I check which devices eats another 5G memory?

Comment: Post output of `cat /proc/meminfo`.

Answer (score -1):

**As mentioned in the comments by Mr Pang, this answer is only valid for hard drives, not for RAM.**

e.g. see [Gigabyte or Gibibyte (1000 or 1024)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949135/gigabyte-or-gibibyte-1000-or-1024) or  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20140814132922-176099595-mb-vs-mib-gb-vs-gib/

---

I guess this is linked to the difference between GB and GiB.

1 GB = 1000MB

1 GiB = 1024MiB

When selling memory (or hard drives) it is more interesting to write GB, but usually we're measuring GiB.

Comment: It is true for hard drives, but not for memory