# What are the difference between M and Mi in Kubernetes resources documentation?

Tags: kubernetes, memory, storage

Reading Kubernetes documentation:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/

```
128974848, 129e6, 129M, 123Mi
```

What are the differences  between  M and Mi here?

If I want to request 128GB of RAMs, how many Mi is the correct number? 128000Mi? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gigabyte or Gibibyte (1000 or 1024)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40949135/gigabyte-or-gibibyte-1000-or-1024)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

"MB" is the [metric unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#Multiple-byte_units), where 1 MB = 10<sup>6</sup> B and 1 GB = 10<sup>9</sup> B.

"MiB" is the power 2 based unit, where 1 MiB = 1024<sup>2</sup> B = 1048576 B.

Thus, 128 GB = 128 · 10<sup>9</sup> B = 122070.3 MiB.

Comment: And just because it's fun to say, MiB is pronounced "mebibytes" ✨

Comment: Thank you. It is really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

So I would suggest to refer this article to get an understanding.

[CPU and Memory units in kubernetes](https://medium.com/swlh/understanding-kubernetes-resource-cpu-and-memory-units-30284b3cc866)

As you will need to request 128GB of RAM you need to do the below calculation:

128*10^9/2^20 = 122070.3125Mi

which is also same as 119.2092M